# How to save a file with a different name?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Trying to save a file with a different name. Empty file is saved(0 bytes). Also, the file has no extension.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/profiles/ericbidelman.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);

  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(
    { type: 'saveFile', suggestedName: 'myfile'},
    function(writableFileEntry) {
      writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
          console.log("Save complete!");
        };
        writer.write(new Blob(uInt8Array, {type: 'image/jpeg'})); 
      }, errorHandler);
    }
  );
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Err, `image/jpeg`, you're sure? Also, you suggest a filename without a extension, so _what do you expect?_

Comment: Do you mean: accepts:[{extensions: ['png']}]? type: 'image/png'. All the same, the file is saved empty.

Comment: Blob([this.response] Tried it, does not help. File Size: 0 bytes.

Comment: Are you sure the response is non-empty to begin with?

Comment: If we write: 'Blob([this.response])' I receive an error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61118/discussion-between-xan-and--).

Comment: "Are you sure the response is non-empty to begin with?" Yes. console.log(this.response) - ArrayBuffer: byteLength: 3412